# React checkbox get (un)checked after the second click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox, checkboxlist

Below is the part of the react component where a dynamic checkbox is listed:

```
   <div className="pb-4">
       <p>Choose the task owner(s):</p>
       {
           peerIds.map(id => {
               if (currentUserId != id)
                   return (
                       <label className="checkbox-inline mr-3">
                           <input onChange={onChange_TaskOwner}
                               type="checkbox"
                               name="taskowner"
                               checked={st_taskOwnersId.filter(function (item) {return (item == id)}).length > 0}
                               value={peers[id].id} />
                           <span>{peers[id].fullName}</span>
                       </label>

                   )
           })
       }
       <div style={{ clear: 'both' }}></div>
   </div>
```

In the above code I set `checked` to false/true if the current id is already in the hook state object called `st_taskOwnersId`.

I store the Ids of the checked items using `hook` as below. `onChange_TaskOwner` function updates the `st_taskOwnersId` depending on whether it is `checked` or `unchecked`:

```
const [st_taskOwnersId, set_taskOwnersId] = useState([] as any);

const onChange_TaskOwner = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target.checked)
        set_taskOwnersId([...st_taskOwnersId, event.target.value]);
    else
        set_taskOwnersId(st_taskOwnersId.filter(function (item) {
            return (item != event.target.value);
        }));
}
```

The code runs without errors. The only problem is I have to click twice to check/uncheck the check boxes.  I have no clue why this is happening. Any help?

Comment: One issue I see is you aren't setting a `key` on repeating elements. Should also use `some()` instead of `filter().length`. Far more efficient both in number of iterations and memory

Comment: Try using `camelCase`, `!==`, `===`, no need to declare a `function` use the short syntax for it. Maybe put some sandbox because the bug can come from another place...

Comment: @charlietfl I appreciate the help.  I did changes based on both comments, but the problem is not solved. Still, I have to click twice.. Any problems you see about the use of `hook`?

Comment: Have you confirmed `onChange_TaskOwner()` is firing each time? Hard to help more without a reproducible example in a sandbox

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the problem is on `onChange_TaskOwner` function. You should remove `event.preventDefault();` call.

I tried to reproduce your component on this [codepen](https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/dBEdOm), without the `event.preventDefault();` works fine, if you add it, the same kind of error start happening.

Comment: Thanks! Although not sure `why` it was behaving like that with `preventDefault`.

Comment: Just add the `preventDefault` inside the `onChange` function on codepen and you will see it was the reason. At least, one of them, not sure.

Comment: Sorry, `why` was missing in my comment :) Thanks again!